# Spring Boot App runs scheduled job twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

My Problem is that the scheduled method "updateMembers" is called twice.
I googled for hours now and all i found was that the Problem may is that the class Scheduler is initialized twice but i don't know how to fix this.
Any suggestions?

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class Scheduler {

@Autowired
PersistenceService persistenceService;

@Scheduled(cron = "* */15 * * * *")
public void updateMembers(){
    try {
        persistenceService.updateMembers();
    }catch (IOException e){
        Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName())
                .error("Scheduled updating of guildmembers failed due to: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Maybe the Problem is somewhere else? 
On my local machine this behaviour didn't occur. On my webserver the second call is fired up after ~47 seconds. The job needs about 2 minutes

Comment: Have you tryed different class for configuration and sheduling bean ?

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean with different class? I created a Class ONLY to contain this scheduled Method

Comment: Two java classes. One annotated with configuration and second for Sheduled method. Like appConfig and MyBean in this example: http://websystique.com/spring/spring-job-scheduling-with-scheduled-enablescheduling-annotations/

Comment: If a job runs twice it is scheduled/detected twice. Make sure your configuration class isn't loaded twice.

Comment: @kulatamicuda I tried this solution but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with another Cron String: cron = "0 */15 * * * *"

Comment: I am facing same issue. My cron is cron="00 10 17 * * *" what modifications needed.

Comment: This is not helpful.